# Minecraft FTB Ultimate server crash (OS Related?)

Tags: java, operating-system

(Originally posted this on StackOverflow and was told that it wasn't the correct site to post on - I think ServerFault is the correct site, but tell me if otherwise).

(ServerFault didn't like me posting more than 2 links, so here's a link with all the links: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5569386)

Having some problems with my FTB server. Whenever a player places a turtle in the world, the server crashes.

Crash report: (SEE HEAD OF POST)

Full Log: (SEE HEAD OF POST)

The server is running a stock FTB Ultimate install. Nothing what so ever has been added to it.

The only mention of this bug I've found is this: (SEE HEAD OF POST)

Which seems to suggest that it could be an issue with the OS I am using (ArchLinux).

Here's the output of 'uname -a', in-case that's needed: (SEE HEAD OF POST)

Here's the output of 'java -version', in-case that's needed: (SEE HEAD OF POST)

Thanks for your help, 
- Alex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my research, you're using OpenJDK which CC (computercraft) doesn't support. Install Oracle's JDK and you should be fine.

Reference: https://github.com/MinecraftPortCentral/MCPC-Plus/issues/557

Note that the appropriate package varies on your flavor of Linux, but this'll give you something to go by. I'm not familiar enough with Arch Linux for that particular package. :-)

Comment: Thanks very much! Manage to fix it by installing the official jre7 from oracle. Seems odd that CCTurtles wouldn't work with openjdk to me, but whatever. Thanks again! - Alex